# Tasks with recurring reminders synced between Android and Windows

Tags: windows, gratis, android, productivity, reminders

So there seem to be a lot of todo list apps supporting recurring notifications, a reminder like "every 2 days", "every week, monday and wednesday", etc. Currently I'm using [Tasks](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.tasks&hl=en) for Android, which does everything I could ever want.

There are also a lot of services syncing your tasks between platforms.

Unfortunately I still haven't found anything that combines the two.

Requirements:

- Recurring reminders on Android and Windows via Notifications (Chrome Notifications are ok)
- Create and edit your tasks on both platforms (just syncing notifications with Cortana or Pushbullet is not enough)
- Free at least for those basic features

Comment: I used http://taskcoach.org/ fo ryewars onm Windows (an excellent app). When the Android verison came out, I wanted what you want. I achieve it by synching the data file with DropBox. I know that that might not be what you are looking for, but you might consider it if you don't get an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about [Wunderlist](https://www.wunderlist.com/home)? It seems to meet all your requirements.